# jhipster liquibase doesn't update database

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I m trying to add a new entity, I don't use the full hot reload, so I created a db-changelog-002.xml file with the new table to be created in the changeset of the file. Then I ran a mvn spring-boot:run, but my database doesn't get updated with the new table.
Is it normal?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You must add your file to master.xml file, like below.

```
<include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/db-changelog-002.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

No Need to create another db-changelog-002.xml file.just add another change set in our Db-ChangeLog.xml file.It will work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. check in the `pom.xml` file the database setup under the `liquibase-maven-plugin` artifact, make sure the (url, username, password, etc.) are  fine
2. run `mvn liquibase:diff` to create the "new_changelog.xml" file
3. `<include>` the "new_changelog.xml" in the `master.xml`, check the date-time of the file to be sure that it was correctly created
4. run the application again

...then cross your fingers, and with a bit of luck the tables will be created !!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to `<include>` in `master.xml`.
2. Make sure to check `LOCKED` column in table `databasechangeloglock`. If locked then unlock it.
3. Make sure to add database information in `pom.xml` under `liquibase-maven-plugin`.
4. Sometimes JHipster doesn't update the Database even though everything is perfectly fine. In that case, you can forcefully update your Database by running this command `mvnw -X liquibase:update`

Answer (score 0):

I must configure the liquibase database information in your `pom.xml` file