# JHipster: Generate an entity - how to?

Tags: jhipster

When I

```
yo jhipster:entity MyEntity
```

the generated code is taking no notice of the MyEntity table definition in db-changelog-002.xml. For example, I am expecting the fields on the table to be listed in the generated html. Instead I am getting the 3 default fields for id, text and date.

The db-changelog-002.xml file has been generated by Liquibase using their instructions for generating it from a fresh start. It looks fine as far as I can tell. I put it into the \src\main\resources\config\liquibase directory, along with db-changelog-001.xml

How can I debug? Are my expectations incorrect?

Comment: I had success with restarting the entire stack, executing a clean build.  There's another answer that suggests there is another XML file you have to create, but this step was unnecessary for me. Let me get a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691455/jhipster-liquibase-doesnt-update-database

Answer (score 2):

- If you are running in "hot reload" mode, then he Liquibase file should be generated, and the database schema should be updated. This the "normal" scenario, and it works surprinsigly well given how complex this task is.
- However, the HTML page is not updated. No work has been done to implement this, but this would be a good idea, I'll have a look at it.